# How to insert text infront of text in table under column

Tags: ms-access

I am working with at able and I have imported data from excel into this table. Each text in the column below has different text in it, and I'd like to put ID: in front of all of the ones I selected, as not all fields will have the ID: in front of it so I don't want to apply a format to the whole column. How would I do this?

[image: This is what the column looks like:]

I want to be able to select the circled data in the "notes" field of the table, then put ID: in front of them all.

Comment: I'm having trouble making any sense out of your question. What do you mean "put ID: in front of" and "apply a format"? Conditional formatting in Access is handled on a row-by-row basis, not columnar. You might consider rewriting your question to make it clearer what the problem is.

Comment: Does my most recent edit make more sense?

Comment: Do you want to update the Notes column to add "ID: " to each field value which doesn't already have it?

Comment: Yes, and only the fields I select as some future fields in that column I wouldn't want ID: to be in front of the text.

Comment: What method do you plan to use to inform Access which rows are selected?

Comment: selecting them by hand, by clicking the first record then pushing shift, and clicking the last record that I want to select. For example, Click CTAS033 then hold shift, and click CTAS089. All the fields in between are selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the first who may understand the author ;-), do you want this?

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Notes = 'ID:' & Notes
WHERE (Notes NOT LIKE 'ID:*');
```

This Access update query prepends 'ID:' string before Notes without it.

1. In Access, you create a query, name it qryUpdNotes for example, change type to UPDATE. Save it and double click it. Access will do the rest of the job
2. Use DAO in VBA:
   CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE MyTable SET Notes = 'ID:' & Notes WHERE (Notes NOT LIKE 'ID:*');"

I use this:

```
Function daoExecuteSql(ByVal strSQL As String) As Long
'
  Dim nDone As Long
'
  Dim db As DAO.Database
'
  On Error GoTo ErrorStatus
'
  Set db = CurrentDb
  db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
'
  nDone = db.RecordsAffected
'
  On Error GoTo 0
'
' db.Close
  Set db = Nothing
'
  daoExecuteSql = nDone
'
  Exit Function
'
ErrorStatus:
'
  MsgBox "daoExecuteSql(): " & strSQL
'
  Set db = Nothing
  daoExecuteSql = 0
'
End Function
```

And Call it like this in a Sub/Macro:

```
Dim strSQL
strSQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET Notes = 'ID:' & Notes" _
  & " WHERE (Notes NOT LIKE 'ID:*');"
daoExecuteSql strSQL
```

Comment: In Access, you create a query, name it qryUpdNotes for example, change type to UPDATE. Save it and double click it. Access will do the rest of the job...